# Can we call a JavaScript function by clicking link from a Watson conversation response?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm implementing a Watson conversation chat, I want to call some Javacript function written in my website by clicking the button/link from Watson response.

Comment: Have you tried on your own to see if its possible or not before asking here?

Comment: It depends on how you implement it...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, but the javascript function call will be part of your application logic. Your application can choose to display a javascript link based on the identified intent or other context data supplied in the Watson Conversation response (now named Watson Assistant).

There's a developerWorks tutorial on building a chatbot that demonstrates a full stack solution with a javascript chatbot, Node.js application, and Watson API calls. If you study how this application works, you should gain insights into how to include a javascript link:

https://developer.ibm.com/courses/all/chatbots-watson-lets-talk-national-parks/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the sample above, or we have also implemented a feature called "actions" which can either link to an IBM Cloud function to run everything in the cloud, or you can do it client side more like above. Here is the documentation:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions